# Issues with looping and displaying pictures

Tags: python

I am working on an ASL (american sign language) program where the user enters a letter, and in return they get a picture of the proper signing. I can get it to work with one letter at a time, but i would like to get whole words. 
heres the loop im working on:

```
from images import Image
print('*** Welcome to the ASL Translator ***')
print('Press ENTER to quit at any time')
letter = input(str('What letter/word would you like to translate (A-Z): '))

#breaking the user input into letters
seperate = list(letter)

i = 0
for i in range(len(seperate)):
    if seperate[0] == 'A' or seperate[0] == 'a':
        image = Image('A.gif')
        image.draw()
        i += 1
    if seperate[1] == 'B' or seperate[1] =='b':
        image = Image('B.gif')
        image.draw()
        i += 1
    if seperate[2] == 'C' or seperate[2] == 'c':
        image = Image('C.gif')
        image.draw()
        i += 1
```

this is what i have that works for one letter at a time.

```
if letter == 'A' or letter == 'a':
    image = Image('A.gif')
    image.draw()
    i += 1
elif letter == 'B' or letter == 'b':
    image = Image('B.gif')
    image.draw()
    i+= 1
elif letter == 'C' or letter == 'c':
    image = Image('C.gif')
    image.draw()
    i+= 1
elif letter == 'D' or letter == 'd':
    image = Image('D.gif')
    image.draw()
elif letter == 'E' or letter == 'e':
    image = Image('E.gif')
    image.draw()
elif letter == 'F' or letter == 'f':
    image = Image('F.gif')
    image.draw()
elif letter == 'G' or letter == 'g':
    image = Image('G.gif')
    image.draw()
elif letter == 'H' or letter == 'h':
    image = Image('H.gif')
    image.draw()
```

.
.
.
. etc all the way to z

thanks in advance if you can help me! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
from images import Image
print('*** Welcome to the ASL Translator ***')
print('Press ENTER to quit at any time')
letter = input(str('What letter/word would you like to translate (A-Z): '))


for ltr in letter.upper():
    if os.path.exists("%s.gif"%ltr):
       image = Image("%s.gif"%ltr)
       image.draw()
```

I think should work

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from images import Image
print('*** Welcome to the ASL Translator ***')
print('Press ENTER to quit at any time')
letter = input(str('What letter/word would you like to translate (A-Z): '))

#breaking the user input into letters
seperate = list(letter)

for i in seperate:
    i=i.upper()
    image = Image(str(i)+'.gif')   
    image.draw()
```

Comment: would there be a way to display more than one .gif pictures per display? so i could have the whole word up at once instead of one letter at a time? @BHAT IRSHAD